# Find unknown event given its conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, conditional-probability

If it is known that:
$P(A)=0.65,  P(B)=0.25 , P(C)=0.10$
And that:
$P(X|A)=0.15,  P(X|B)=0.25,  P(X|C)=0.85$

How would one solve for $P(X)$?

Comment: One question. Is anything said about union or intersection $A,B,C$?

Comment: It seems natural to assume they're disjoint since the probabilities add to 1, but it really should be explicitly stated.

Comment: Okay, perhaps should have clarified this before, but the events are: A=new car, B=elderly car and C=old car. X is the probability that a given car has a flaw. This would mean that event X is dependent on the car's age (A,B,C). Nothing else is given in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If $A, B, C$ are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, we can find $P(X)$ by

$P(X) = P(A)P(X|A) + P(B)P(X|B) + P(C)P(X|C)$

$P(X) = 0.65 \times 0.15 + 0.25 \times 0.25 + 0.1 \times 0.85$

$P(X) = 0.245$

Comment: Please don't give answers to questions without context. In addition, please use $a \times b$ or $a \cdot b$ instead because in MathJax, the letter 'x' will render as $x$, not the multiplication sign.